# Import only brace/modes you need

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bundle

It really bothers me, that I can't avoid warnings of bundle size, only because I'm importing brace. 
What wonder me the most is, I can see from the webpack bundle analyzer, that it imports all possible modes from brace - eventhough I'm only calling a few of them. It won't even change if I only import one single mode.
How can it be? What can I do, to cut off this huge package?

[image]

Comment: `brace` is huge. It uses its own modular system. It cannot be tree-shaken with Webpack because it doesn't use ES modules. If you're not happy with this, fork it to remove things you don't need, or don't use it. Why did you prefer it over Ace? It's not even maintained.

Comment: Hm, have I been using it the wrong way? I'm importing AceEditor as component, and setting the mode-prop in AceEditor, by importing some languages from brace.

Comment: I guess you used it correctly. It just works like that.

Comment: So conclusion is, its not possible to cut off some of these 5 mbs from brace?

Comment: Only by forking it.